# Swap view controllers in a container view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a container view inside of a view controller and I want to switch the view controller in the container view when a button is pressed in the main view. Any suggestions? Also if it is possible I would prefer swift if you give any examples.
Thanks

Comment: Check this too. https://github.com/iaaqib/ContainerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not started your work yet I would suggest using `UITabViewController` in place of container view in `UIViewController`. Using `UITabViewController` has one advantage over using container view that you dont have to manage Child View Controller your `UITabViewController` manages it all. As apple documentation says `UITabBarController` is a specialized view controller that manages a radio-style selection interface.

But if you have already started working on container view, you may want it working.I too learned regarding container view from the same link which @iOSGeek has shared. Every things is clearly explained. You can follow the same link and you are good to go.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks a lot will do!